# How to install imagick module PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I believe that I have followed all the steps in this tutorial:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows

I know that it worked with an earlier version of XAMPP.

However, with this version no imagick module shows up. The only strange thing I noticed was that my PHP version is 7.2.4 but there is no correstponding version on

https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.3/windows

So I tried both 7.1 and 7.0 with no success. Maybe someone knows where to get the appropriate php_imagick.dll or what else might be wrong.

Comment: I've the same problem as you and I found this ( https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html and https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/imagick/3.4.3/ ). Did not try it yet, hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. Followed https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html and it worked!